# Problema con estilos (background-color) en proyecto angular

Tags: css, angular, component

Tengo un prototipo hecho con html y css, lo quiero pasar (copié y pegué) a Angular el tema es que todo se deforma en angular (el background color no se aplica completo), los estilos no se aplican bien y no sé por qué, mi componente se llama index y la hoja de estilos es index.component.scss

[image: Proyecto-html]

[image: index]

El CSS (que funcionaba bien fuera de Angular) es el siguiente:

```
* {
    background-color: #1B0088;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.container{
    margin-top: 150px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 235px;
    left: 456px;
    width: 455px;
    height: 72px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 1;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 356px;
    left: 638px;
    width: 91px;
    height: 91px;
    opacity: 1;
}

a {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 495px;
    left: 612px;
    width: 143px;
    height: 37px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: normal normal normal 18px/26px Arial Black;
    
}
```

Comment: Normalmente el archivo index.html ya cuenta con una estructura básica del html para el header y el body, y veo que es lo que tienes en el componente, y a no ser que hayas hecho algún cambio ahí, esa podría ser la razón por la que copiar y pegar simplemente no funciono. En cualquier caso creo que se necesitan más detalles para saber qué pasa.

Comment: index es un componente creado por mí, ahi puse mi html (index.component.html)

Comment: Si, pero en angular por defecto ya hay un archivo que se encarga de la etiqueta html, header, body, y probablemente lo estás repitiendo